# MUI Select event retruns to undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have created a form using MUI where i used a Select component which isnt working as intended, my state:

```
  const [formdata, setformdata] = useState({});
```

my event handler:

```
  const onchangehandle = (e) => {
setformdata((prevState) => ({
  ...prevState,
  [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
}));
```

};

my Select component:

```
<Select
  name="year"
  placeholder="Select year..."
  value={formdata.year}
  onChange={onchangehandle}
>
   <Option value="I">I</Option>
   <Option value="II">II</Option>
   <Option value="III">III</Option>
   <Option value="IV">IV</Option>
 </Select>
```

the select does not return any value
help appreciated.

Comment: what version of material UI are you using? Material UI v4 and v5 use the component `MeneuItem` to display optiosn for the `Select` component.

Comment: Where are you observing the "returned value"?  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] and indicate specifically what observation you are making?

Comment: @J.Cutshall sorry for not specifying but i am using Joy UI from mui, docs: https://mui.com/joy-ui/react-select/

Comment: @David this is what am trying to do: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jbrh9f?file=src/App.js, it works for other elements but only Select returns null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sample code of [Select](https://mui.com/base-ui/react-select/#controlled-select) component, `newValue` is set as the second parameter of `onChange` event. For this reason, you need to change `onChange` function handlers of both your `Select` components like this:

```js
// for select year
onChange={(e, newValue) =>
  handleChange({
    target: {
      value: newValue,
      name: "year"
    }
  })
}

// for select gender
onChange={(e, newValue) =>
  handleChange({
    target: {
      value: newValue,
      name: "gender"
    }
  })
}
```

You can take a look at [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mui-select-event?file=src%2FApp.jsx) for a live working example of this solution.

Comment: Also is there any way to return the innerHTML/Text of the selected option? currently it returns the number which would require some parsing.

Comment: I think innerText can be reached from the first parameter (e event) but I do not suggest using it. It won't be easier than your current parsing.